# A long riddle: My First is in Apple but not in Lear, …

Tags: riddle, word, letters

My **First** is in *Apple* but not in *Lear*
My **Second** is in *Fiona* and also in *Flower*
My **Third** is in *Integrate* and also *Interrogate*
My **Fourth** is in *Neon* and *Never* an "E"
My **Fifth** is not coffee, of course not it's ...
My **Sixth** is in *Love*, try Spanish - it's "He"
My **Seventh** is in *Beetle* and also in *Meat*
My **Eighth** is in *Snake* and also in *Hiss*
My **Ninth** is just the same as my Eighth
And then right here is a small Space
My **Tenth** is in *Ride* and also in *Row*
My **Eleventh** is also my three
My **Twelth** is in *Down* but not in *Grown*
My **Thirteenth** is in *Dinner* and also in *Deed*
My **Last Two** are two different letters in *Lee*

Comment: *”And then right here is a small Space”* DVL10 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: @Randal'Thor Hahah, thanks for reminding me! $(+1)$

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Second word

*My Tenth is in Ride and also in Row*

> That can only be **R**.

*My Eleventh is also my three*

> I'll come back to this.

*My Twelth is in Down but not in Grown*

> That can only be **D**.

*My Thirteenth is in Dinner and also in Deed*

> Either D or E.

*My Last Two are two different letters in Lee*

> E and L, in some order.

So the second word is:

> R, ?, D, D or E, EL or LE. Clearly it's **RIDDLE** (and now we know the 3rd letter is also I).

### First word

*My First is in Apple but not in Lear*

> That can only be **P**.

*My Second is in Fiona and also in Flower*

> F or O.

*My Third is in Integrate and also Interrogate*

> We know this is **I**.

*My Fourth is in Neon and Never an "E"*

> Not quite sure what this means. Probably O or N.

*My Fifth is not coffee, of course not it's ...*

> Tea or **T**.

*My Sixth is in Love, try Spanish - it's "He"*

> This is **L**, pronounced "el".

*My Seventh is in Beetle and also in Meat*

> E or T.

*My Eighth is in Snake and also in Hiss*

> That can only be **S**.

*My Ninth is just the same as my Eighth*

> Another **S**.

So the first word is:

> P, F or O, I, O or N, T, L, E or T, S, S. That must be **POINTLESS**.

### Final answer

> POINTLESS RIDDLE. Well, if you say so!

Comment: Well done. I'd vote up but I've reached my daily limit

Comment: @WilliamPennanti hah, it’s good to hear that I’m not the only one who reaches their daily voting limit (DVL) :P

Comment: @WilliamPennanti No worries, I've gone *way* over the daily limit on reputation today anyway. Upvotes after UTC midnight will be gratefully appreciated :-P

Comment: Of course (if i can)

Comment: @William You can vote now (if you didn't already) :-P